# How to fix getting time in Safari for Javascript

Tags: javascript, gettime

When getting the time in Chrome and Firefox I get the number of milliseconds for a given date, but for Safari it Shows NaN. Any ideas why this would happen? I would need it to show also the number of milliseconds -as well- in Safari.

PHP code

```
$date = $product->getDateEnd();
```

Javascript:

```
var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $date ?>").getTime();
```

Comment: What’s the value of `$date`…?

Comment: It returns the number of milliseconds: 1551222000000, but this only happens in Chrome and Firefox; in Safari, it returns NaN

Comment: What. Is. `$date`? Not `countDownDate`, but `$date`.

Comment: That's a date I have configured in the backend of Magento; echo $date; returns 2019-02-27 00:00:00, and alert(countDownDate); returns 1551222000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you got tis pattern `yyyy-mm-dd`. This isn't an officially supported `Date` pattern, some browsers like Chrome and Firefox will support it, but Safari not.
Try to use other versions, like :

`yyyy/mm/dd
mm/dd/yyyy
mm-dd-yyyy`

Comment: Then why is it that an alert on this variable:

var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $date ?>").getTime();

would return NaN in Safari

but an alert on this variable 

var now = new Date().getTime();

Would return the correct number of miliseconds in safari?

Comment: because your `new Date("<?php echo $date ?>")` is returning an `invalid date` To compare, try this in chrome or firefox: `new Date("badDateFormat").getTime();` Will return `NaN`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Is there something I can add to new Date("<?php echo $date ?>").getTime() in order to make it return a valid date?

Comment: format the `"<?php echo $date ?>` to a valid date for safari. But why you need the date from PHP ??

Comment: Because that's a date that has been configured at the Magento backend for each product, so the dates can vary per product.

Comment: then just save it to a variable and format it properly for safari.

Comment: I've formatted it to yyyy/mm/dd and then it's working as intended; thank you